# How can I make ExpandableListView not selectable?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, expandablelistview

I have a expandable list view with all the list already expanded. I don't want the user to be able to selected any parent items (group items). I have made it so that clicking it will not collapse the list, but cannot figure out how to make the item un-selectable.

Comment: Is this the your problem?

check this [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126581/can-i-make-a-listview-item-not-selectable

Comment: no unfortunately expandablelistview doesn't have isEnabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use isChildSelectable method to make your required child item clickable. Maintain the isChildSelectable boolean state in your child model object.

```
@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return yourmodel.isChildSelectable;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't trigger for the group (parent) items. Only children. So it really doesn't answer OP's question (which is my question as well)

Comment: @Nilzor My answer is about 'cannot figure out how to make the item un-selectable.'

Comment: @Nilzor By making the group click listener `null` and adding `android:clickable="false"` to group_item layout and expand each group in `getGroupView` method like

   `@Override
   public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      
      ((ExpandableListView) parent).expandGroup(groupPosition);

      ....
      return convertView;
   }`

   will solve your problem I think

Answer (score 1):

if anyone was wondering, this is how I solved it:

I added these two lines into my ExpandableListView xml.

```
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" 
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you have already tried, but disabling the entire list should made it impossible to select something.

Comment: what do you mean disable entire list?

Comment: I mean calling setEnabled() on the ExpandableListView. The interpretation varies per class, but it shouldn't react to clicks anymore

Answer (score 0):

You can set the header as unclickable before returning the view in getGroupView() of the adapter: `view.setClickable(true);` or `view.setFocusable(false);` depending on what exactly you want.

Edit: changed setClickable(false) to setClickable(true). Making the view clickable means that you can't click what is behind, the list selector.